# Systemd pause boot while script runs

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, startup, raspbian, init-script

I have a script that I want to run at boot, and whilst it runs I would like it to pause the boot process.

I have tried the systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=setup script
Before=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/my/setup/script

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

but this continues the boot process so the graphical desktop still runs even though my script has not finished yet.

Is this possible to do with systemd?

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use gdm as a login manager,

```
[Unit]
Description=setup script
Before=gdm.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/my/setup/script

[Install]
```

If you don't use gdm, find out which service starts xorg and put that in the `Before=` line.
Explanation: There were two problems: 1. in your case `default.target` is likely a symlink pointing to graphical.target. so `Wants=default.target` indicates that it should be started after the graphical target 2. `Before=default.target` does not work: Targets are used to report to systemd when certain stages in the boot process are **finsihed** starting, not when they start to be loaded. So using a target only makes sense if you want to start something **after** that target was reached not before or if you want to make sure that the target is only achieved once your service finished loading.

Comment: And if I'm not using a desktop environment? Should I use `Before=multi-user.target` ?

Comment: Could you please make more clear what it is that you are trying to achieve. Above you said your problem was that the graphical desktop runs before your script is done. How can that be if you are not using a desktop environment?